# Exporting index.html to a file on button click

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Hello is there a way to export the current html page to a file.

i have used the following but it would not work with a button. it would upload when i load the page and not work with the button.

```
<?php 
// Start the buffering //
ob_start();
?>

<?php
file_put_contents($_POST["prefix"] .'_index.html', ob_get_contents());
?>
```

I have also tried jquery to try and do a key press for Ctrl+s to save the page
but i cant manage to get any keypress to work. i was testing the f11 in this code

```
$('#cmd').on('click',function(){

var event = jQuery.Event('keypress');
event.which =91; 
event.keyCode = 91; //keycode to trigger this for simulating enter
jQuery(this).trigger(event);

alert('hi');


});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
          
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
                <h3 align="">how to save index.html</h3><br />  
                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
                    
                        <button  class="cmd" id="cmd">generate </button> 
                </form>  
                <br />  
           </div>  
           <br />  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

here is my updated code with everything i have tried.

```
<?php 
ob_start();
?>

<body id="target">
  <div id="content">
    <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag</h3>
    <a class="upload">Upload to Imgur</a> 
    <h2>this is <b>bold</b> <span style="color:red">red</span></h2> 
    <p>Feedback form with screenshot This script allows you to create feedback forms which include a screenshot, created on the clients browser, along with the form. The screenshot is based on the DOM and as such may not be 100% accurate to the real representation
      as it does not make an actual screenshot, but builds the screenshot based on the information available on the page. How does it work? The script is based on the html2canvas library, which renders the current page as a canvas image, by reading the
      DOM and the different styles applied to the elements. This script adds the options for the user to draw elements on top of that image, such as mark points of interest on the image along with the feedback they send. It does not require any rendering
      from the server, as the whole image is created on the clients browser. No plugins, no flash, no interaction needed from the server, just pure JavaScript! Browser compatibility Firefox 3.5+ Newer versions of Google Chrome, Safari & Opera IE9
    </p>

  </div>
  
  <button  class="cmd" id="cmd">generate </button>
</body>
<?php 
//if(isset($_POST['cmd']))
//    echo 'hi';
  //echo ("<script>alert('Uploaded File index.html Successfuly!')</script>");
?>

</html>

<script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// $(document).ready(function(){
 
//  $('#cmd').click(function(){
//   // $(document).bind('keydown', 'Ctrl+s', fn);
//   var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
// e.which = 91; // m code value
// e.altKey = true; // Alt key pressed
// //e.which =
//  });
// });

$('#cmd').on('click',function(){

var event = jQuery.Event('keypress');
event.which =91; 
event.keyCode = 91; //keycode to trigger this for simulating enter
jQuery(this).trigger(event);

alert('hi');


});


</script>
```

Comment: are there any alternatives other then the ob_get_contents() ?

Comment: if i click on the button and it does that yes.

Comment: There is an alternative please check my answer.

Answer (score -1):

HTML RESPONSE is Source Code received from Client.

So as I see, you are using PHP to receive the SourceCODE.  You can generate your response from another PHP script, than RUN it with PHP ->   then get the response  as TEXT than SAVE.

if you do not understand, I will explain more detailed.
-> php ->

```
$output = shell_exec('php my_aim.php');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";    # THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED TO  SAVE !!!
```

2. How apache works ?
   At the background Apache using php to run the script than put output as response .

Web is based ,  Response Request Session.  :  Session comes from request.

You need to pass sessions also .   So you should put your session parameters as arguments to command line script. OR you can deserialize and serialize your session.

Comment: please elaborate because i am genuinely confused. how would i apply this to my code?

Comment: Please write here path of the  php file that you want to save as HTML. URL. Write here the link. or ...